# Homotopy equivalence induces Deformation Retraction if... (Hatcher's AT)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm currently studying Allen Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology
and I've come across argument in a proof about which I'm not sure
why it works. It can be looked up on page 353.

> **Proposition 4.15.** If $(X,A)$ is an n connected CW pair, then there exists a CW pair
> $(Z,A) \simeq (X,A) \operatorname{rel} A$ such that all cells of $Z − A$ have
> dimension greater than $n$.

note a homotopy $H: Z \times [0,1] \to X$ is $\operatorname{rel} A$ for $A \subset Z$
if $h_t= H(-\times \{t\})\vert_A$ is independent of $t$.

> **The Proof:** Starting with the inclusion $ A \hookrightarrow X$ attach cells
> to $A$ of dimension $n + 1$
> and higher to produce a CW complex $Z$ and a map $f :Z \to X$ that is the identity
> on $A$ and induces an injection on $\pi_n$ and isomorphisms on all higher homotopy
> groups. The induced map on $\pi_n$ is also surjective since this is true for the composition $f :A \hookrightarrow Z \xrightarrow{f} X$
> by the hypothesis that $(X,A)$ is $n$ connected. In dimensions below $n$, $f$
> induces isomorphisms on homotopy groups since both inclusions
> $ A \hookrightarrow Z$ and $ A \hookrightarrow X$
> induce isomorphisms in these dimensions. Thus $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence,
> and hence a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead’s theorem.

> To see that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence $\operatorname{rel} A$, form a
> quotient space $W$ of the mapping cylinder $M_f$
> by collapsing each segment $\{a\} \times [0,1]$ to a point, for $a \in A$. Assuming
> $f$ has been made cellular, $W$ is a CW complex containing $X$ and $Z$ as subcomplexes,
> and $W$ deformation retracts to $X$ just as $M_f$ does. Also,
> $\pi_i(W,Z) = 0$ for all $i$ since $f$ induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups,
> so $W$ deformation retracts
> onto $Z$.

My question is about the last claim in the proof: Why $W$ deformation retracts onto $Z$ if
$\pi_i(W,Z) = 0$ for all $i$? In explicite terms why there exist a
family of maps $h_t: W \to W, t \in [0,1]$, such that
$h_0= id_X $(the identity map), $h_1(W)= Z$ and $h_t \vert _Z= id_Z$ for all $t$?

also note the construction of the **mapping cylinder** as the quotient
of the disjoint union $(Z \times [0,1]) \coprod X$ obtained by identifying
each $(z, 1)  \in X \times [0,1]$ with $f(z) \in X$.)

Comment: That's part of the Whitehead theorem, discussed a bit earlier in the book.