# About proof of Prop 4.15 in Hatcher's AT (latest edition)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I got stuck while reading Hatcher's proof of this proposition, which is in page 353-354.

> **Proposition 4.15.** If $(X, A)$ is an $n$-connected CW pair, then there exists a CW pair $(Z, A)\simeq (X, A) $ rel $A$ such that all cells of $Z−A$ have dimension greater than $n$.

> **The Proof:** Starting with the inclusion $ A \hookrightarrow X$ attach cells
> to $A$ of dimension $n + 1$
> and higher to produce a CW complex $Z$ and a map $f :Z \to X$ that is the identity
> on $A$ and induces an injection on $\pi_n$ and isomorphisms on all higher homotopy
> groups. The induced map on $\pi_n$ is also surjective since this is true for the composition $A \hookrightarrow Z \stackrel{f}\rightarrow X$
> by the hypothesis that $(X,A)$ is $n$ connected. In dimensions below $n$, $f$
> induces isomorphisms on homotopy groups since both inclusions
> $ A \hookrightarrow Z$ and $ A \hookrightarrow X$
> induce isomorphisms in these dimensions. Thus $f$ is a weak homotopy equivalence,
> and hence a homotopy equivalence by Whitehead’s theorem.

> To see that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence $\operatorname{rel} A$, form a
> quotient space $W$ of the mapping cylinder $M_f$
> by collapsing each segment $\{a\} \times [0,1]$ to a point, for $a \in A$. Assuming
> $f$ has been made cellular, $W$ is a CW complex containing $X$ and $Z$ as subcomplexes,
> and $W$ deformation retracts to $X$ just as $M_f$ does. Also,
> $\pi_i(W,Z) = 0$ for all $i$ since $f$ induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups,
> so $W$ deformation retracts
> onto $Z$.

(I just copied the proof from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321232/homotopy-equivalence-induces-deformation-retraction-if-hatchers-at).) My question is about this claim near the end of the proof.

> Also, $\pi_i
> (W,Z) = 0$ for all $i$ since
> $f$ induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups.

I know why $f$ induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups, but I don't know how it implies $\pi_i
(W,Z) = 0$ for all $i.$ I think this does not follow from the long exact sequence of homotopy groups since $Z\stackrel{f}\rightarrow X\hookrightarrow W$ is not the right inclusion map. Could somebody give  me help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $Z \hookrightarrow W \to X =f$ and $W \to X$ is a deformation retract. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @AndresMejia Ah, I think you are right. I was just too careless. Thank you.

Comment: not at all, you are being exceptionally careful! Glad you worked it out

Comment: @yzhou If it is clear now, you should write an official answer to your own question.